# Hybrid lifestyle in Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC that also have a WCF Service included in the same proyect.

Im using Autofac to manage dependency injection. The problem is that when the application is accessed throught web, I need the dependencies to be instanced per Http request. And when the application is accessed throught WCF, I need the dependencies to be instanced per dependency.

In Castle.Windsor, there is a proyect to manage hybrid lifestyles (in [this link](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com.ar/2010/06/hybrid-lifestyles-in-windsor.html)).

I need something similar, something like:

```
builder.Register<UnitOfMeasureService>(x => new UnitOfMeasureService())
            .As<IUnitOfMeasureService>().HybridLifetimeInstance();
```

Are there a workaround to manage the instance lifetime depending on when the application has a `HttpContext` or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Autofac does not have support for custom lifestyle managers.**

Autofac lifetimes revolve around scopes, which are nestable and can be optionally tagged with a known ID. That's how instance-per-HTTP-request works: A nested scope "tagged" with a known value ("AutofacWebRequest") is created when a web request comes in. The hierarchy looks like this:

- Container (root lifetime scope)

  - Web Reqeust Scope (tagged "AutofacWebRequest")

    - Any child scopes you might create in your code

When using `InstancePerHttpRequest` it's basically the same as `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest")`. If you resolve the type, it falls back until it finds a scope with that name and then uses the same instance in that tagged scope.

In standard WCF hosting, Autofac resolves everything out of a child scope you can get from the instance context (`AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime`). You could create a child lifetime scope from that and manually tag it, then resolve your dependencies like this:

```
var opScope = AutofacInstanceContext.Current.OperationLifetime;
using(var requestScope = opScope.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"))
{
  // Resolve InstancePerHttpRequest items from requestScope
}
```

However, there's no way to do that automatically and the WCF hosting mechanism isn't currently architected in a way you can "plug in" and do this - if you needed the web request scope automatically created, **you'd have to roll your own WCF hosting mechanism based on the Autofac source code**.

The **other option is to have two different containers** - one for your web stuff and one for your WCF stuff - and register the component with a different lifetime in each container.

Beyond that... **there's really no way to "switch" lifetimes based on context**. A component gets one lifetime declared and has to live with it for that component registry.